# error using the command \setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

Tags: sectioning

Upon trying to add extra sections to my document, I tried to use the command \setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}, However, upon compilation, I get the error "Undefined control sequencesubsubsubsection"
Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[%
  hidelinks,
  colorlinks=true,
  breaklinks,
  allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 
\section{يييي}
\subsection{سيشسي}
\subsubsection{شسيسشسي}
\subsubsubsection{شسيسشسيسش}
\subsubsubsubsection{شسيسشسيشسي}
\subsubsubsubsubsection{شسيسشسيسشسي}

\end{document}
```

Comment: levels 4 and 5 are `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`, you would have to define `\subsubparagraph` which is not defined by default.

Comment: @David, I need numbered sections that, also ones that can be displayed in the table of contents

Comment: @Silva that is a different question and has probably been asked. Just to be clear you want 6 levels of numbered sections? What do you want the formatting to look like?

Comment: Yes, but as I say levels 4 and 5 are `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` not subsubsubsection.

Comment: headings (including paragraph) are numbered if you increase  `secnumdepth` as well as `tocdepth` but the standard classes only have levels 0-5

Comment: @strongbad, book class support till 3 levels of sectioning, to make more levels you should use the command \setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}, the issue here is that such command s not wotking.

Comment: @stronbad, https://www.mediafire.com/file/z4l8sbefbb37imh/New_Microsoft_Word_Document_%282%29.docx/file

Comment: You should take a look at § 3.9 of the `titlesec` documentation, *Creating new levels and changing the class*, pp.9-10.

Comment: There are two issues here, one you are using undefined commands, if you only went to level 5 you would simply need to use \paragraph and \subparagraph,  then the other issue is that book does not define a level 6 so you need to define \subsubsubparagraph

Comment: your MWE misses out `\section` if you use `\section` after `\chapter` would you still need the level 6 headings?

Comment: @David, I do still need the 6 headings in addition to the \section heading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard classes define commands for heading levels 0-5, you can set `secnumdepth` greater than this, but that does not automatically define commands, you need to define any deeper level commands if needed. You can use a package such as `titlesec`, but here I just copy the definition of `\subparagraph` making the obvious changes of `5` to `6` where the level is specified. Note your MWE omits the `\section` level heading, I added that in while defining the new level. If adding `\section` back means you do not need the `\subsubparagraph` level then most of the code here is not needed.

[image]

I didn't have the fonts you used so I have used Latin script here but that is unrelated to the heading issue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[%
  hidelinks,
  colorlinks=true,
  breaklinks,
  allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@subsubparagraph{6}
\providecommand\theHsubsubparagraph {\theHsubparagraph.\arabic{subsubparagraph}}
\newcounter {subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph {\thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{12em}{6em}}
\newcommand\subsubparagraph{\@startsection{subsubparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{zzz} 
aa
\section{zzz}
aa
\subsection{zzz}
aa
\subsubsection{zzzz}
aa
\paragraph{zzzz}
aa
\subparagraph{zzzzz}
aa
\subsubparagraph{zzzz}
aa

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ David, is it better to use \subsection, or is \subparagraph the correct one? Also can I set the indentation and style of the last sections since they seem to have different indentation settings?

Comment: `\subsection` is level 2, `\subparagraph` is level 5, so it is not a case of one better than the other.  the standard classes make headings 4 and 5 run in rather than display but you can change that (just negate the appropriate argument) but that would mean changing the definitions of `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` in addition to the above. But perhaps you would prefer to use a simpler package interface rather than simply copying/modifying lines from `book.cls` as here. Styling headings is a different question though really. @Silva